# Forcing a DialogFragment to not recreate after orientation change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

When I'm changing the orientation of my app with a visible `DialogFragment` opened from my `Activity`, the dialog will be recreated. How can I forcefully dismiss it?

For now I tried to store it as a member in my activity and dismiss it in onCreate but at this point it seems to be null;

Comment: Get a reference to the fragment using the FragmentManager and then dismiss it.

Comment: @Luksprog: Can you elaborate?

Comment: When you show a DialogFragment use a tag string with the show() method. In the onCreate() of the activity use the FragmentManager to look for a fragment with that tag. If you find a fragment associated with that tag it means you have previously shown the DialogFragment, in which case you dismiss it.

Answer (score 7):

To disable recreations of DialogFragments of a specific type, you can override `onCreate` in your derived `DialogFragment` class and dismiss the dialog in case it is being recreated:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Luksprog mentioned in the comments, a solution could be:

Give a tag to your DialogFragment at creation:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment.newInstance(...).show(fragmentManager, "myTag");
```

Search for it and dismiss it in `onCreate`

```
MyDialogFragment dialog = ((MyDialogFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myTag"));
if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

I think it would be more efficient to disable the recreation of the DialogFragment altogether but I don't know if that's possible.